# Como insertar un código JSON en Wordpress

Tags: html, json, wordpress, api

resulta que me piden insertar este código JSON en una pagina de wordpress con DIVI pero no he podido lograrlo, vi algunos tutoriales que lo hacen con HTML pero no me funcionó, si de pronto alguien me puede ayudar como estructurarlo se lo agradezco de antemano, este es el código

`{"symbol":"BMY_BTC_COP","timestamp":"20201121172400","rates":{"ask":66590000,"bid":60460000}}`

Sale de esta url https://api.bitmoney.co/rates/lbtc/btc/cop

La idea es mostrar esto:[image: La idea es mostrar esto]

Comment: Creo que vas a a ocupar ser mucho más específico, no sabemos que estás haciendo ni tampoco nada de tu implementación. Este JSON  `{"symbol":"BMY_BTC_COP","timestamp":"20201121172400","rates":{"ask":66590000,"bid":60460000}}` es solo una variable.

Answer (score 0):

Html como tal no puede leer json, para eso necesitaras usar otro lenguaje que lo entienda para luego mostrarlo en html, por ejemplo javascript, para ello ingresas tu json en una variable y luego ingresas a los valores de esa variable y los muestras en un objeto html basandote en un id o una clase, por ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        let variable = { "symbol":"BMY_BTC_COP","timestamp":"20201121172400","rates":{"ask":66590000,"bid":60460000}}
        jQuery('#symbol').html( '' + variable['symbol'] + '' );
        jQuery('#timestamp').html( '' + variable['timestamp'] + '' );
        jQuery('#rates').html( '' + variable.rates['ask'] + '' );
        jQuery('#bid').html( '' + variable.rates['bid'] + '' );
        console.log( variable );
    </script>
```

en tu html

```
    <div id="symbol"></div>
    <div id="timestamp"></div>
    <div id="rates"></div>
    <div id="bid"></div>
```

Siendo esos los valores que retorna el json, en mi caso estoy usando jquery, ya en producción como tal tu json posiblemente reciba información mediante una petición GET, posiblemente a la url que adjuntaste, así que esto es solo un ejemplo de como mostrar lo que el json recibe en tu html.

Para probar esto en divi solo debes de ingresar el script en el footer de tu sitio y meter los divs con sus IDs en un campo de divi.

Puedes ver en consola los valores que retorna usando `console.log( variable );`

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a intentar